# Simple javascript execution for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to borrow the JavaScript from http://readable.tastefulwords.com/.

Instead of making it a bookmarklet, I wanted to turn the script into an extension. I DO NOT know a lot of Java, only enough to execute certain things. I figure it'll be easy, just borrow a tutorial Chrome extension template and put the script in somewhere.

Well, about 3 hours of researching and testing, I'm stuck. I can get other simple scripts to run EXCEPT the one from that site.

I have done some searching around and I even used the script design from this one post (last answer on that post): [Run javascript with click on popup.html icon in Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193549/run-javascript-with-click-on-popup-html-icon-in-chrome-extension)

I managed to set up the prompt.js, and the code looks like this:

```
function promptBox()
  {
    _readableOptions=
    {
      'text_font':'quote(Palatino Linotype), Palatino, quote(Book Antigua), Georgia, serif','text_font_monospace':'quote(Courier New), Courier, monospace','text_font_header':'quote(Times New Roman), Times, serif','text_size':'18px','text_line_height':'1.5','box_width':'30em','color_text':'#282828','color_background':'#F5F5F5','color_links':'#0000FF','text_align':'normal','base':'blueprint','custom_css':''
    };
    if(document.getElementsByTagName('body').length>0);
    else
    {
      return;
    }    
    if(window.$readable)
    {
      if(window.$readable.bookmarkletTimer)
        {
          return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
      window.$readable={};
    }
    window.$readable.bookmarkletTimer=true;
    window.$readable.options=_readableOptions;
    if(window.$readable.bookmarkletClicked)
    {
      window.$readable.bookmarkletClicked();
      return;
    }
    _readableScript=document.createElement('script');
    _readableScript.setAttribute
      (
        'src','http://readable-static.tastefulwords.com/target.js?rand='+encodeURIComponent(Math.random())
      );
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(_readableScript);
   }

chrome.extension.onClicked.addListener(promptBox());
```

I just need that last script to work and I am sure it can make the article I want to read "readable".

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you getting an error? If so, please copy the error message here so that others can see what's going on. Also, you might want to edit your question to refer to JavaScript exclusively rather than Java -- the two languages are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your if (document...) statement is guaranteed to do nothing, meaning the rest of the promptBox() function is dead code.

```
if (something)
  ;
else {
  return;
}
```