# Chrome to read when window is focused,aka opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am still fairly new at programing. I have played around with JavaScript before, but it is still tricky for me.

I got this great idea for an extension for Google Chrome- in the future it would be nice to port it into other browsers. For now I think Google Chrome would be the easiest way to develop for.

I investigated a little and finished the [kitties tutorial on the extensions site](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html).

From there it makes sense- easy for the most part, but my idea sounds impossible to me. Simply, the extension would automatically reload the browser when window is selected or focused on the screen. Saves time by not pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (PC), or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Mac), or reload button every time the developer checks an update on code.

I was reading through the API documentation and found the method
`chrome.browserAction.onClick`, is there like `chrome.browserAction.focused`? Is this idea even feasible?

I also have to take in consideration that Chrome is visited by multiple OS. I wonder if Mac OS, Linux, and Windows version need different JavaScript instruction to pull this off? This simple idea is overwhelming...

Thanks for input in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'll want to use [`chrome.windows.onFocusChanged`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#event-onFocusChanged):

> Fired when the currently focused window changes. Will be chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE if all chrome windows have lost focus. Note: On some Linux window managers, WINDOW_ID_NONE will always be sent immediately preceding a switch from one chrome window to another.

Here's an example of how to reload a newly-focused window's active tab:

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
    if (windowId != chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE) {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active:true, windowId:windowId }, function(tabs) {
            if (tabs.length == 1) {
                var tab = tabs[0];
                chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You'll also need to [declare the `tabs` permission](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) in your manifest.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your input. I am still trying to figure this out. I want to trigger the JavaScript code as soon as a user hits the default_icon on the extension toolbar, but no luck yet. Basically I took your advice along with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13193982/1316785... Now the code you shared that is in the html and then the code is triggered in the js, like I have here [link](http://pastebin.com/k2hY8FQ0)?  Not working for me.

Comment: The JavaScript in my answer above will need to reside in a `background.js` file or similar, acting as a [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) defined in your manifest. To make something happen when a user clicks your extension's icon on Chrome's toolbar, you'll need to listen for the [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked) event within your background script.

Comment: I got it to work! Turned out I forgot to declare the entire tabs property. I had `"tabs"` when it should be `"tabs", "http://*/*" , "https://*/*"`