# Chrome extension get DOM text and show it in popup.html on click on button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

There are a ton of information about this on SO and elsewhere, but I couldn't get it to work!

I have this popup.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My popup that should display the DOM</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <button id="btn">Click!</button>
        <input type="text" id="info"> 
  </body>
</html>
```

my manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name":    "Get HTML example w/ popup",
"version": "0.0",

"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
    "js":      ["jquery-2.2.1.min.js","content.js"]
}],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Get HTML example",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": ["tabs"]
}
```

background.js:

```
function doStuffWithDOM(infoHtmlText) {
    alert("I received the following DOM content:\n" + infoHtmlText);
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().info = infoHtmlText;
}


chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id,changeInfo,tab){
        if(changeInfo.status=='complete'){ //To send message after the webpage has loaded
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { status: "ok" },function(response){
              infoHtmlText = $("#domElement").text();
               doStuffWithDOM(infoHtmlText);
            });
          }
})
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    /* If the received message has the expected format... */
    if (msg.status && (msg.status == "ok")) {
        /* Call the specified callback, passing
           the web-pages DOM content as argument */
        sendResponse("something?");
    }
});
```

Is there a simple example, where you can click on a button in the popup and get content from the DOM and show it in the popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code based from your codes:

popup.js

```
function hello() {
   var  name = document.getElementById('info').value;
   alert("Hello " +name);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', hello);
```

popup.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My popup that should display the DOM</title>

  </head>
  <body>
        <button id="btn">Click!</button>
        <input type="text" id="info"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name":    "Get HTML example w/ popup",
"version": "0.0",
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Get HTML example",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

`background.js` :  leave blank (not sure on this on because I'm new at chrome development) but it is working.

I got the answer from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193549/run-javascript-with-click-on-popup-html-icon-in-chrome-extension), if you directly use inline headers you will encounter this error message:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".