# JavaScript function not loading onto chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an XMLHttpRequest which as of right now returns a string in a div tag in the html file, but it is not working.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
  <body onload="renderXML()">
      <div id="news_1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript: [url](http://www.deadstock.ca/collections/new-arrivals/products/nike-womens-bp-qs-air-presto-black-5.xml)

```
function renderXML() {
var xmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlreq.open("GET",url);
xmlreq.responseType = 'json';
xmlreq.send(null);

xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlreq.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlreq.status === 200) {
    var nr = xmlreq.response;
  document.getElementById('news_1').innerHTML = nr.hash.variants[0];
      }
    }

}
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "mypopup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [ {
  "matches": ["*://*/*"],
  "js": ["scripts.js"]
} ]


}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Someone, quick, do we have a canonical question for `onload` in a popup? On topic (and it really should be closed as a duplicate, the only question is finding a good candidate): see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193549/run-javascript-with-click-on-popup-html-icon-in-chrome-extension) is the best candidate so far, any others?

Comment: Whoops. Apologies - I am pretty new to this. Will fix

Comment: It's fine, you ARE new to this. Do note that you should [learn to debug popups](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) - it would give you an error message that would be more helpful in finding a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Ideally for the final product I'd like to use the parsed string from the function (the XML parser would use the current tab url as its source url) and use it as part of a new URL which is then opened in a new tab automatically. Are there any helpful readings that I should look at?